# V-for with simple arrays: what key to use?

Tags: vue.js

I’d like to know how people use v-for with such simple arrays. I think these are the options I have. The first option means there’s no place for simple arrays.

Use arrays of objects instead, explicitly declaring a key for each item.
Don’t use a key in the v-for.

How to display one element from an array?

```
 `<template>:`

    <ul>
        <li v-for="fruit in fruits" :key="fruit"></li>
    </ul>
```

`<script>:`

```
export default {
        data() {
            return {
                fruits: ['apple', 'banana', 'orange']
            };
        }
    };
```

Comment: if every element is distinct, your code example would work out of the box. If there's a risk of duplicates within the array, you could generate a key from the index and the value: `index + '-' + fruit`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, don't put `;` symbols in your script there. Just use commas `,` to separate data, methods, computed, etc.

- You don't have to specify a key if you are not going to use it.
- To display elements in the loop, you just put it in double curly braces `{{ }}`.
- If you will need an index, you can specify it after the item. To display it, you do the same thing, just put it in double curly braces: `{{index}}`

**Codepen:** https://codepen.io/x84733/pen/dKwjBL?editors=1010

```
<ul>
  <li v-for="(fruit, index) in fruits">
    {{index}}: {{fruit}}
  </li>
</ul>

...

data () {
  return {
    fruits: ['apple', 'banana', 'orange'] 
  }
},
methods: {
  ...
}
```